# User Input Using a String to Display on Screen

Tags: c++

I'm writing a basic program to prompt user to enter text, then display user input on screen. I'm using a string to accept user input, but don't know what code to add in string UserInput function? So far my program prompts the user to enter text but it doesn't display on screen. What can I do to make program work?

```css
//Simple loop
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string UserInput(string);

int main(void)
{
 
 string input;

    // Enter user input
 cout << "Enter your input: ";
 cin >> input;

 // Display user input
    cout << "You entered: " << UserInput(input) << endl;
    return 0;
 /*while (number <= 5)
 {
  cout << "Enter your input: ";
  number++;
 }*/
}

string UserInput(string)
{
 //string Input = 
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's pretty convoluted, but the implementation would be `string UserInput(string input) { return input; }`. Of course, you could simply output `input` as is.

Comment: Why do you think you need a function here?

Comment: I didn't know I could use "cout << "You entered: " << input << endl;" to display user input on screen. I thought my function would allow callers to pass input into a function, then output the value on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intent is confusing, this function:

```
string UserInput(string)
{
    //string Input = 
    return 0;
}
```

Doesn't do anything. You are performing a bad cast from the `int` to `string` which causes runtime errors: http://ideone.com/vzoQcw.

Play around this:

```
int main(void)
{

    string input;

    // Enter user input
    cout << "Enter your input: ";
    cin >> input;

    // Display user input
    cout << "You entered: " << input << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to do some consistent modifications of the string with your function user input, then you need to modify the string and return. eg.

```
// Example function to uppercase the string. 
string UserInput(string input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
         input[i] = toupper(input[i]);
    }
    return input;
}
```

[Here is a live example for you to play with.](http://ideone.com/ecoszM)

Comment: Thank you Ben. I'm going to play around with this code. Now I know why it would be useful to use a function.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you dont want to modify the string inside your UserInput-Function, just use

```
cout << "You entered: " << input << endl;
```

If you want to modify it, write your function like this:

```
string UserInput(string s)
{
s = "whatever"; //modify s as you like
return s;
}
```

In C++ function parameters need a type (`string` here) and a name (`s` here) in order to use/modify them.

Comment: If you have some "task" to do with a string that you want to do more than once at different positions in your program or that you want to keep as a "unit" for a different reason.